# PHP Unexpected T_Variable that doesn't actually exist

Tags: php

So, I was trying to write a PHP authentication system, but I cannot run it without getting an error. Specifically, it says the following:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\struct\general\resources\root~index\User.php on line 6
```

I then looked it up, and found out that the error was a common one. However, what was different about mine was that the '$name' variable didn't actually exist. In fact, line 6 is the closing bracket of a function. Here is the full code:

```
<?php

include 'User.php';
function sha512($data){
return hash('sha512', $data);
}//This is line 6
?> 
<html><head><title>Login</title></head><body background="/struct/general/resources/root~index/images/Pig.jpg"<p>Your request is being processed.     Please Wait...</p><br />
<?php
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['__INPUT_2']);
$passwordhash = sha512(htmlspecialchars($_POST['__INPUT_1']));

$user_file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/struct/data/user/data';

$isUser = file_exists($user_file_path . $username . '$' . $passwordhash);



$user = new User($username, $passwordhash);

?>
```

By the way, I am somewhat of a beginner to PHP, so I'm not sure if I matched all the conventions correctly. Anyways, my question is this: Why am I getting an error about a mysterious variable called '$name' when that variable does not exist within the scope of my code, and how should I fix this?

Comment: Could the problem be in `User.php`?

Comment: You need to look at line 6 of your included `User.php` file.

Comment: at the top of your file is `include 'User.php';` therefore the code you have shown is not the file the error is reporting for. what is your user.php code?

Comment: I mean, it says right there in the error `C:\..\User.php on line 6`

Comment: So, are we saying the error is in User.php?

Comment: something something User.php

Comment: Hey maybe you should look in User.php.

Comment: I'm with these guys ^ check `User.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP error reporting is precise in what it states. PHP doesn't lie, even if the actual issue in your code is not the error and/or line PHP has stated in the error.

ie unexpected end at line 200. It might be a missing curly brace at line 140. You need to read about the errors, search for them here and in Google.

"unexpected" anything in PHP errors is usually straight cut, in that it was expecting something before whatever is mentioned in the error.
In this case, `unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE)`, your `$name` variable was not expected, PHP was expecting a closing bracket, or comma, or semi colon to end the previous line, something else.

Look at your line 6 in your file User.php. If that line is absolutely fine, then the error is before it, again, perhaps a missing semi colon for the previous line.